# In which memory section does the uninitialized variable integer 'A' occupy memory?

Tags: c++, linux, x86-64, memory-layout

In the code below, on printing the size of the variable, it says 4 bytes using GCC compiler on my 64 bit Linux system. So, memory seems to be allocated to this undeclared integer. In which memory section does the uninitialized variable integer 'A' occupy memory? Would it be BSS segement as it is uninitialized or stack as it is a local variable? Though it is uninitialized it has default value zero and size of 4 bytes, so I was thinking it would get memory allocation on stack.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{ 
    int A;

    cout << A << endl << sizeof(A);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are variables in C++ stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230584/where-are-variables-in-c-stored)

Comment: `A` is not an "undeclared integer", it is a declared and defined variable which is only not initialized (so, BTW, reading it is undefined behaviour and everything can happen in programs with undefined behaviour). What do you mean with "in which memory section"? What "memory sections" are you thinking about?

Comment: This isn't strictly speaking a C++ question, since "memory sections" are an implementation detail that the language itself doesn't deal with.  Since you mentioned Linux, I added that tag.

Comment: The size of A is not dependent on where it is stored or even if the compiler optimizes it out completely. It is the same as sizeof (int) regardless.

Comment: @WernerHenze Would it be BSS segement as it is uninitialized or stack as it is a local variable? Though it is uninitialized it has default value zero and size of 4 bytes, so I was thinking it would get memory allocation on stack. Need your opinion

Comment: "*In the code below, on printing the size of the variable, it says 4 bytes using GCC compiler on my 64 bit Linux system.*" The `sizeof` operator only cares what type you're asking about. It doesn't tell you anything about `A` specifically, except that its type takes up 4 bytes when stored in memory.

Comment: Why would you care about sections?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So, where would it get memory allocated? on BSS segment or on stack?

Comment: @NeoMitnick Probably nowhere in this case since a register will suffice.

Comment: An uninitialized local (auto) variable doesn’t get initialized to zero like a static variable does. Using the value is undefined behavior.

Comment: @prl I executed the code in Eclipse, the value of A was printed '0' by the compiler

Comment: Yeah, that’s the thing about undefined behavior—it might do what you expect, but you can’t rely on it.

Comment: @NeoMitnick Normally this variable should be on the stack, as it is declared locally in a function (here main). But as David Schwartz pointed out it an optimizing compiler can put the variable into a register (it could not if your code were taking the address of the variable and for example printed it). But in your case with the undefined behavior everything could happen. Your compiler would not need to even allocate an int for A, it could direclty print out a hard coded value which it assumes A always stores,

Answer (score 0):

Programs usually have 4 sections of memory i.e. 
1. Code : This is where the executable instructions of a program are stored.
2. Data : This contains global and static variables that are initialized by programmer.
3. Stack: This is where all the local variables of all functions go along with their declarations, initializations and changes if any. It works on FILO or LIFO.
4. Heap: This is where dynamic memory allocation takes place. In c, you can use **malloc** to allocate memory on heap to a pointer and in c++ you can use **new**.

In your case, since A is just a local variable of the main function, therefore, it should be stored in stack.

Comment: The compiler may also store local variables in registers.